# Error installing pg through capistrano deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, capistrano

I have rails 2.3.8 app
I have pg in my gemfile but showing error after deployment

```
servers: ["apphost"]
    [apphost] executing command
 ** [out :: apphost] Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
 ** [out :: apphost] 
 ** [out :: apphost] /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
 ** [out :: apphost] checking for pg_config... no
 ** [out :: apphost] No pg_config... trying anyway. If building fails, please try again with
 ** [out :: apphost] --with-pg-config=/path/to/pg_config
 ** [out :: apphost] checking for libpq-fe.h... no
 ** [out :: apphost] Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
 ** [out :: apphost] *** extconf.rb failed ***
 ** [out :: apphost] Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
 ** [out :: apphost] necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
 ** [out :: apphost] details.  You may need configuration options.
 ** [out :: apphost] 
 ** [out :: apphost] Provided configuration options:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From parsing the log the Gem can't find pg-config, either postgres isn't installed on that server yet or you need to configure the paths correctly.

Comment: what does `which pg_config` give you on your server?

Comment: /usr/pgsql-9.0/bin/pg_config

Comment: then youu need to change your bundle config to use that path

`bundle config build.pg --with-pg-config=/usr/pgsql-9.0/bin/pg_config`

Answer (score 3):

You're missing postgres header files required for compilation of C code in the gem.

If you're on a source based distribution like gentoo, installing postgresql package should be enough.

If you're on a debian-like system, they traditionally do not include header files along with libraries, and you have to install corresponding `*-dev` package. In your case, on ubuntu, it's `libpq-dev` :

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

Comment: server is on redhat.. Also istalled "yum install postgresql-devel".. still facing issue

Comment: [This is what package installs](http://fr2.rpmfind.net//linux/RPM/fedora/devel/rawhide/i386/p/postgresql-devel-9.3.0-1.fc21.i686.html). Can you confirm that file `/usr/include/pgsql/server/libpq/libpq.h` is there ?